# How to use npm slug for hindi language in node.js

Tags: node.js, slug

I am trying to implement slug in node.js. I have downloaded npm slug. That is working fine for English however clients want to have hindi as his language for some atricle so, How to implement Hindi language as it is returning nothing .

```
var title = fields.title;
slug.defaults.mode ='pretty';
slug.defaults.modes['rfc3492'] = {
replacement: '-',      // replace spaces with replacement 
symbols: true,         // replace unicode symbols or not 
remove: null,          // (optional) regex to remove characters 
lower: true,           // result in lower case 
charmap: slug.charmap, // replace special characters 
multicharmap: slug.multicharmap // replace multi-characters 
  };
                var slug1=slug(title);
                 console.log(slug1);
```

Comment: the default slug.charmap appears to currently support only: latin, greek, turkish, russian, ukranian, czech, polish, latvian, lithuanian, romanian, vietnamese. shown here: https://github.com/dodo/node-slug/blob/master/slug.js

Comment: @KorreyD: How can i add other language in this.

Answer (score 1):

`slug` [supports Hindi as of v3.0.0](https://github.com/Trott/slug/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300) released in May 2020.

```
console.log(slug('नमस्कार'))
// Prints: namasakara
```